# How to save translations and properties for a multilingual site?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Site language is determined by the domain or subdomain. site.com - English, fr.site.com - French. There is a table "domains" in which these records are stored.

I created a polymorphic table "domainable_attributes" for saving translations and several properties (many entities use this table):

- id
- domain_id
- entity_id
- entity_type
- title
- link
- text
- sorting
- is_active

But I ran into the problem that some entities need additional properties that depend on the domain (language). In the future, other entities may also receive properties depending on domain.

- Products: waranty,video
- Collections: in_slider,in_navigation,on_total_page
- Brands: type

I have several solutions to this problem, but I do not know what will be the most correct:

1) Add all these columns to the table "domainable_attributes" as nullable.

2) Create tables such as "product_domainable_attributes", "brand_domainable_attributes", "collection_domainable_attributes"
But then, the activity and sorting, for example, of the collections will be in the table “domainable_attributes”, and in_slider,in_navigation,on_total_page - in the "collection_domainable_attributes" table.

3) Rename table "domainable_attributes" to "translations" and delete is_active,sorting. (only translations will be stored in it). And creating tables such as:

- article_domainable_attributes (is_active,sorting)
- news_domainable_attributes (is_active,sorting)
- page_domainable_attributes (is_active,sorting)
- rubric_domainable_attributes (is_active,sorting)
- product_domainable_attributes (is_active,waranty,video)
- brand_domainable_attributes (is_active,sorting,type)
- ...

Has anyone done something like this? What can you advise?

Comment: Might the warranties for Canada and France be different for legal reasons?  Yet Canada needs two languages: en and fr.  Look at how "Locales" are handled for clues of what might be needed.  Meanwhile, British English and American English have a small number of spelling and phrasing differences (ise vs ize; "to hostptal" vs "to a hospital"; "company are" vs "company is".)

Comment: @RickJames, the guarantee meant that the product has a guarantee text, which must be translated for all languages used on the site. site.com - the text of the guarantee is displayed in English, de.site.com - the text of the guarantee is displayed in German.

Comment: OK, a "guarantee" is a piece of the page.  It is probably translated into all languages.  Where does it fit on the page -- is that flexible?  I assume that not all pages need a guarantee, so either the layout needs to be data-driven, or "guarantee" is standard on every page, but NULLable when it does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

For bulk translation of text (eg the body of a news article), I would have an id on one table; that id would link to another table with id+language being the primary key and a `TEXT` column being in different languages.  Note:  Use `utf8mb4`.

For short words and phrases, the `id` could be the English version.  (Or pick your favorite lingua franca -- Roman, French, and Russian are no longer very popular; Hindi and Swahili are probably to limited.)

For links, dates, and other things that could be formatted differently for locales, I would build in some function mechanism that 'dynamically' computes the string to display.  Eg, "06 mai 2019" vs "May 6, 2019"; "1,234.56" vs "1.234,56".  In these cases, the *value* is constant; the *formatting* (and some built-in translation, eg month names) is built into the function.

Links might be easily functionized:  `https://the.site/<<locale>>/foobar_page.html`

(I don't understand your question, but maybe I have given you some clues.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly what I need. As I wrote above, I have an “domainable_attributes” table in which translations and two properties “sorting” and “is_active” are stored. Now it turned out that some entities have additional properties that depend on the domain of the site (language). For example, the essence of the Collection, in addition to text translations, activities and sorting, also has three domain-dependent (language-specific) properties:
"in_slider", "in_navigation", "on_total_page".

Comment: For example, in the English version one collection may have “in_navigation” as a "true", and in the German version as a "false"
The question is that I do not understand where it is better to store these properties.

Comment: @myglazik - Unfortunately, I am lost on each of your quoted terms in these Comments.